# In scala, is there an idiomatic way to handle closing and reopening an underlying stream when trying to wrap it with other streams?

Tags: scala, try-catch, inputstream

I am trying to open a stream, try to decompress it as gzip, if that fails try to decompress it as zlib, and return the stream for further use.  The underlying stream *must* be closed in the case of exceptions creating the wrapping decompression streams, as otherwise I will run into resource exhaustion issues.

pbData is a standard, non-resettable, InputStream

There has to be a cleaner way to do this.

```
    val input = {
      var pb = pbData.open()
      try {
        log.trace("Attempting to create GZIPInputStream")
        new GZIPInputStream(pb)
      } catch {
        case e: ZipException => {
          log.trace("Attempting to create InflaterInputStream")
          pb.close()
          pb = pbData.open()
          try {
            new InflaterInputStream(pb)
          } catch {
            case e: ZipException => {
              pb.close()
              throw e
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: InputStream doesn't have method open(). Which exact interface does pdData object's class implement?

Comment: apologies - pbData is a PortableDataStream, the open() method returns an InputStream.

Comment: I'm exploring using a BufferedInputStream wrapper, which allows for the use of reset(); I think this may greatly simplify the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your process is actually iteration over `InputStream` instance generators. Check this, far more idiomatic solution compared to a lot of nested try-catch'es:

```
val bis = new BufferedInputStream(pbData.open())
// allows us to read and reset 16 bytes, as in your answer
bis.mark(16)

// list of functions, because we need lazy evaluation of streams
val streamGens: List[Any => InputStream] = List(
  _ => new GZIPInputStream(bis),
  _ => new InflaterInputStream(bis),
  _ => bis
)

def firstStreamOf(streamGens: List[Any => InputStream]): Try[InputStream] =
  streamGens match {
    case x :: xs =>
      Try(x()).recoverWith {
        case NonFatal(_) =>
          // reset in case of failure
          bis.reset()
          firstStreamOf(xs)
      }
    case Nil =>
      // shouldn't get to this line because of last streamGens element
      Failure(new Exception)
  }

val tryStream = firstStreamOf(streamGens)

tryStream.foreach { stream =>
  // do something with stream...
}
```

As a bonus, if you'll need to add trying more stream generators, you will have to add exactly one line into `streamGens` initialization. Also, we won't need to add `bit.reset()` invocation manually.

Comment: thanks! I like this.  Key was really wrapping with the BufferedInputStream; once I did that, it made it a lot cleaner anyway.  This cleans up the try/catch cruft nicely though.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
def tryDecompress(pbData: PBData, ds: InputStream => InputStream *): InputStream = {
  def tryIt(s: InputStream, dc: InputStream => InputStream) = try {
    dc(s) 
  } catch { case NonFatal(e) => 
    close(s)
    throw e
  }

  val (first, rest) = ds.head -> ds.tail
  try { 
    tryIt(pbData.open, first) 
  } catch { 
    case _: ZipException if rest.nonEmpty => 
      tryDecompress(pbData, rest)
  }
}

val stream = tryDecompress(pbData, new GZipInputStream(_), new InflaterInputStream(_))
```

(Too bad scala's `Try` does not have `onFailure` ... this could look much nicer if it did :/)

Answer (score 0):

```
val result: Try[InflaterInputStream] = Try(new GZIPInputStream(pb)) match {
    case res@Success(x) => res
    case Failure(e) => e match {
      case e: ZipException =>
        Try(new InflaterInputStream(pb)) match {
          case res2@Success(x2) => res2
          case Failure(e2) => e match {
            case _ => pb.close()
                      Failure(e2)
          }
        }
      case  ex@_ => pb.close()
                    Failure(ex)
    }
  }
```

Comment: this won't work; GzipInputStream reads bytes from pb, so pb has to be re-created in order to reset it.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using a BufferedInputStream to wrap the underlying stream, then resetting it between each decompression library attempt, looks pretty clean.

```
val bis = new BufferedInputStream(pbData.open())
// allows us to read and reset 16 bytes
bis.mark(16)
val input: InputStream = {
  try {
    log.trace("attempting to open as gzip")
    new GZIPInputStream(bis)
  } catch {
    case e: ZipException => try {
        bis.reset()
        log.trace("attempting to open as zlib")
        new InflaterInputStream(bis)
      } catch {
        case e: ZipException => {
            bis.reset()
            log.trace("attempting to open as uncompressed")
            bis
          }
      }
  }
}
```